# Undefined index in post php

Tags: php

I have a form code php

```
<form action="CR/add.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Date</label>
       <input id="date" type="text" name="date"  class="date" value="<?php echo $datenow; ?>" required <?php if($user!="admin"){echo "disabled";}?>>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>  Input Data</button>
</form>
```

I get some error when I click the submit button. The error is `Undefined index variable $date`. I want only admin users to be able to edit the fill.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post more code please ? especially the part where you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include the related PHP code for where the `$date` variable is declared or assigned a value.

A good way to do this would be to check if the variable was supplied using `isset` http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Example:

```
$date = '';
if(isset($_POST['date'])){ 
    $date = $_POST['date']; 
}
```

** Will need to see more of your code to give a more specific example.

Answer (score 0):

@ Kurnia Rocki - Just replace your code with this:

```
<script>
    function check()
      { var user = document.getElementById('user').value;
        if(user!='admin')
           { alert('Only admin can update');
             return false;
           }
        else
         return true;

      }
    </script>

   <form action="CR/add.php" method="post" onSubmit="return check()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input id="date" type="text" name="date"  class="tanggal" value="<?php echo $datenow; ?>" >
      </div>
      <input id="user" type="text" name="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" style="display:none;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-edit">
      </span>Input Data</button>
    </form>
```